# How to create the bubble which we see on the google page which asks you to set the Google as your homepage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I want to suggest visitors to my website to set my website as their homepage. I wanted to show a popup but found it too intrusive for the visitor to see a giant popup every time they came to the website.

I wanted to replicate the "make google your homepage" button that you see on the top right corner of the google page when you don't have google as your homepage, it seemed very non intrusive.

[image: Like this]

I am not able to figure out how I should build it. Can any one tell me what its called?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Having a popup/tooltip show the message once, and if / when clicked away, have that fact stored in either a cookie or on localStorage, will prevent it from showing again every time you load the page. As for creating a button I have no idea what looks like, that's gonna be a stretch. (No, there is no such button on my Google page).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in most of the browsers, mostly because of a security concern. If in fact this was possible, then everyone would do this automatically to make you visit their website.

Maybe you just can tell people how to set their homepage using the browser custom settings to set your website as their homepage. Maybe you should create a popup based on `cookies` with a message and links to the browser instructions on how to set your website as a homepage.

For this I think you can refer to these links:

[Popup cookie once per browser session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986726/popup-cookie-once-per-browser-session)

[Setting a cookie to only show popup once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887815/setting-a-cookie-to-only-show-popup-once)

[Display A Popup Only Once Per User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189428/display-a-popup-only-once-per-user)

[Making my javaScript popup to appear only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775440/making-my-javascript-popup-to-appear-only-once)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the asnwer. I am not forcing people to set my website as their homepage. I just want to show a non intrusive popup to guide them to the "how to set website as homepage" page. I am giving the user the full control to set or not set as homepage.